# Applying map function to OO method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am wondering whether I can use the Python inbuilt function `map` (written in C) to replace a for loop that currently contains a call to a method of a class instance.

The following code is a slim template of what part of the class looks like. External to this class, we call the method `buildPatientsFromPatid` which loops through entries from a list of string, calls inline the private method `__buildPatientFromPatid` which returns a `patient_instance` (instance of class Patient) that is immediately passed to the for loop embedded method `addPatient` to add to the `patients` object.

```
class some_class():

    def __buildPatientFromPatid(self, patidStr, featureList):
        # do something
        # ....
        return patient_instance    

    def buildPatientsFromPatid(self, patidList, featureList) -> Patients:
        # go through each patidList entry, build a new Patient and assigned to a PatientsClass instance
        patients = Patients()
    
        for patidStr in patidList:
            patients.addPatient(self.__buildPatientFromPatid(patidStr, featureList))

        return patients
```

I envisage some variation  on:

```
patients = Patients()

patients= map(self.buildPatientFromPatid(<this_must_change>, featureList),  patidList)
```

I'm just not sure how to make this work.

Comment: `lambda patid: self.buildPatientFromPatid(patid, featureList)`!?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use `map`? Maps are lazy in Python - you'd still need to iterate over/exhaust the map object in order to actually compute the results.

Comment: The map function will return a generator. 
```
map(lambda x:x, [])
>>> <map at 0x7fb549818b80>
```
and unless you iterate over it, the func will not be executed.
I don't think map would be a good idea in this case. What you are doing seems good enough.

Comment: You aren't building a list or other sequence of values, so the `for` loop is the appropriate construct for simply repeating a sequence of method calls.

Comment: Things would be different if, instead of having to call `addPatient` repeatedly, you could pass an appropriate list directly to `Patients.__init__` when you first create the object.